# how do you cancel a parachain proposal or referendum?

Tags: extrinsic, governance, democracy

what specific extrinsic(s) should be run by a technical committee member in order to initiate the cancellation procedure for a running referendum?

the polkadot wiki states this is possible here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance#canceling

i am looking for the specific steps a technical committee member should take in order to initiate a vote by all of the technical committee members on whether or not the referendum should be cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposals are done though the [Democracy Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/democracy). The pallet has an extrinsic called `emergency_cancel` that can only be called by the `Cancellation Origin`

Here's a quote from the democracy pallet docs

```rust
//! #### Cancellation Origin
//!
//! This call can only be made by the `CancellationOrigin`.
//!
//! - `emergency_cancel` - Schedules an emergency cancellation of a referendum. Can only happen once
//!   to a specific referendum.
```

So in order to cancel the proposal you must call that extrinsic using an account that is part of the collective assigned to the `Cancelation Origin` defined in the pallets config. Egg:

```rust
impl pallet_democracy::Config for Runtime {
  ...
 type CancellationOrigin = EitherOfDiverse<
        EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 2, 3>,
    >;
 ...
}
```

You can watch this [Deep Dive of the pallet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgcUWK2E9Jo) done by the Delivery Services team at parity